# Microsoft sql server 2014 Error on insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, sql-server-2014

When I insert into table with this code I have this error.

```
INSERT INTO Ridic values(
1, 'Franta' , 'Popkorn'  ,
2, 'Slavěna', 'Zíková'   ,
3, 'Havel'  , 'Bravenec' ,
4, 'Rudolf' , 'Stibor'   ,
5, 'Miloš'  , 'Vorlíček' ,
6, 'Agáta'  , 'Krobotová'
)
```

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

But when I try insert only one row everything is OK

```
INSERT INTO Ridic values(1, 'Franta' , 'Popkorn')
```

I use SQL server 2014 management studio.
there is table:

```
create table Ridic
(
UserID int primary key,
Jmeno varchar(10),
Prijmeni varchar(10)
)
```

Comment: [SQL SERVER – Three Methods to Insert Multiple Rows into Single Table](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/08/29/sql-server-three-methods-to-insert-multiple-rows-into-single-table-sql-in-sixty-seconds-024-video/)

Comment: Also your column data types are `Varchar` you have some unicode characters in your data like `ě` , `á` and `š` etc. You need to do two things, 1. change the data type from varchar to `NVARCHAR` . 2. When inserting data into columns prefix your string with `N` like ....  `values(
1, N'Franta' , N'Popkorn') `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every set of parenthesis in a `values` clause refers to a single row. In other words, this statement attempts to insert a single row with 18 columns, which of course fails (the line breaks, like any whitespace are inconsequential). Instead, you should have six sets of parenthesis, each with three columns:

```
INSERT INTO Ridic VALUES
(1, 'Franta' , 'Popkorn'  ),
(2, 'Slavěna', 'Zíková'   ),
(3, 'Havel'  , 'Bravenec' ),
(4, 'Rudolf' , 'Stibor'   ),
(5, 'Miloš'  , 'Vorlíček' ),
(6, 'Agáta'  , 'Krobotová')
```

Comment: I would suggest using field names also `INSERT INTO Ridic (UserID, Jmeno, Prijmeni) VALUES .....`

Answer (score 0):

Test the following statement.

```
INSERT INTO Ridic values(
1, 'Franta' , 'Popkorn'),
(2, 'Slavěna', 'Zíková'),
(3, 'Havel'  , 'Bravenec'),
(4, 'Rudolf' , 'Stibor'),
(5, 'Miloš'  , 'Vorlíček'),
(6, 'Agáta'  , 'Krobotová')
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot some brackets:

```
insert  into Ridic
values  (1, 'Franta', 'Popkorn')  ,
        (2, 'Slavěna', 'Zíková')  ,
        (3, 'Havel', 'Bravenec')  ,
        (4, 'Rudolf', 'Stibor')  ,
        (5, 'Miloš', 'Vorlíček')  ,
        (6, 'Agáta', 'Krobotová')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT  INTO Ridic
VALUES  ( 1, 'Franta', 'Popkorn' )  ,
        ( 2, 'Slavěna', 'Zíková' )   ,
        ( 3, 'Havel', 'Bravenec' ) ,
        ( 4, 'Rudolf', 'Stibor' )  ,
        ( 5, 'Miloš', 'Vorlíček' ) ,
        ( 6, 'Agáta', 'Krobotová' );
```